# Why are so many boot options in my bios?

Tags: boot, uefi, bios

Boot into bios setting:

[image]

It shows so many boot option--UEFI OS in the menu,almost all of them is redundant,how can delete them ?
I don't like the way to unplug cmos battery and plug to reset.

Comment: Wow, that's a bit of a mess. I know lists like that that get generated/updated automatically can end up a little bloated, but that seems excessive! I would want to clean it up too.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be on topic. Maybe stackoverflow is a better place for this.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani stackoverflow would be entirely the wrong place for this question, it has nothing to do with programming.    https://superuser.com/ might be appropriate but, since the only actual OS listed is Debian, it's reasonable to assume that the OP wants to know about linux tools for examining and modifying the UEFI boot options. ...as in ddawson's answer with `efibootmgr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install efibootmgr. It will let you examine and edit that list.

```
$ efibootmgr
```

gives you the simple list, and

```
$ efibootmgr -v
```

shows some of the gory details, which are not easy to understand but might give you hints about what all of those entries do, so you can make sure they really are unnecessary.

```
# efibootmgr -b XXXX -B
```

will delete bootnum XXXX (from the above lists). Obviously, be careful not to delete any you shouldn't, or you might have a problem that *must* be fixed, instead of a mere annoyance.